# Confusion with how V8 turns function into hot function?

Tags: javascript, v8

I was learning how V8 works and as I found out, there is something called "hot function" that V8 turns a function into after repeated invocation. The questions I would kindly like to ask are, **firstly**, is function turned into hot function after repeated one-after-another execution in a loop? **Secondly**, after what exact repeated execution, V8 knows that it needs to convert a function into hot function?